# recursive variadic template can't deduce argument

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

I have a recursive function template where type 'T' is used internally but the variadic template argument is used only for generate the recursive template.

```
int qi(int t) {
    return 0;
}

template <typename T, typename... U>
int qi(int t) {
    //do stuff...
    return qi<U...>(t); // <--- error here
}
```

If I try to compile it, I get the error `could not deduce template argument for 'T'`. Why can't the function be deduced to the non template variant of qi (`int qi(int t){}`) ?

Comment: How do you expect it to deduce `T` or `U`?  There is nothing of type `T` or `U` anywhere in your code. `T` and `U` must appear in the arguments of `qi` in order for them to be deduced

Comment: ... in other words, when you execute `qi(3)` in your program, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: ` qi<U...>(t)` will never call the non template function, because even with an empty template parameter list, it's still a (call to a) template function.

Comment: `qi<>(int )` is not the same thing a `qi(int )`.

Comment: @all that makes sense, but is there a possible way to go through all template arguments without using them as arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that `qi<>(int )` and `qi(int )` are not the same call - the former is still a template, so the overload you attempted to write as your base case actually isn't. It's actually worse since the initially obvious solution:

```
template <>
int qi(int ) { ... }
```

since won't work since that isn't an explicit specialization of your `qi` (since your function template takes at least one type). The simplest thing would be to actually use arguments to overload with:

```
template <typename...> struct sequence { };

template <typename... T>
int qi(int t) { return qi_helper(t, sequence<T...>{} ); }
```

With:

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
int qi_helper(int t, sequence<T, U...> ) {
    // do stuff
    return qi_helper(t, sequence<U...>{}); 
}

int qi_helper(int t, sequence<> ) {
    // base case
}
```

You can accomplish a similar thing with a struct `QiHelper<T...>` that is specialized for the two cases (since you *can* partially specialize a class template).

If you didn't want to return anything, you could forward to a helper like this:

```
template <typename T> void qi_helper(int t) {
    /* logic for single type */
}

template <typename... T>
void qi(int t) {
    using swallow = int[];
    (void)swallow{0,
        (void(qi_helper<T>(t)), 0)...
    };
}
```

Depending on what you actually want to return, that may or may not still be possible.

Comment: Btw, is there a name or some keywords for this "helper" aproach, i could use the next time for googleling before asking a question?

Answer (score 3):

First, declare `qi` to take *any* number of template arguments, including zero arguments.

```
template <typename... TU>
extern
int qi(int t);
```

We must eventually provide an implementation of this. But first, we are allowed to provide any number of fully-specialized (not partially-specialized) templates. So, we implement the zero-argument one:

```
template < > 
int qi< >(int ) { 
    return 0;
}
```

It's a specialization (because there is a `<` after `qi`) and a full specialization (because the `< >` after `template` is empty.

We would like to implement the non-specialized `qi` template now. We're not allowed to do any partial specialization, and we don't want to do full specialization as that would mean having to implement every set of types you might use. So that means we must implement something with this signature: `template <typename... TU>   int qi(int t) ...`

We're stuck with `TU`, and no obvious way to 'peel off' the `T` to be left with the pack `U...`. The simplest thing is to pass off the implementation to a helper function:

```
template<typename T, typename... U>
int qi_helper(int t) {
    // do any other interesting stuff
    return qi<U...>(t); 
}

template <typename... TU>
int qi(int t) {
    // just pass on the call to qi_helper
    return qi_helper<TU...>(t);
}
```