# Variadic template recursive types passing

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic

I found almost satisfying solution for my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326458/recursive-variadic-template-cant-deduce-argument)(2nd answer), but I cant use code written this way in another compilation unit, since putting code in header file causes linker to complain about multiple function definition and putting only declaration in header file causes linker undefined reference problem.

Here is my code:

```cpp
template <typename... types>
void foo();

template<>
void foo<>() {
    return;
}

template<typename type, typename... types>
void foohelper() {
    foo<types...>();
}

template <typename... types>
void foo() {
    foohelper<types...>();
}

int main() {
    foo<int, int>();
}
```

And here is what I want to achieve:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    template<>
    void foo<>() {
        return;
    }

    template<typename parser, typename... parsers>
    void foohelper() {
        foo<parsers...>();
    }

    template <typename... parsers>
    void foo() {
        foohelper<parsers...>();
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo<int, int>();
}
```

But this causes following error during compilation:

```
explicit specialization 'void A::foo(void)' is not a specialization of a function template
```

Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: Did you try moving general (non-specialized) `foo` declaration above the specialized one, and moving all definition to after the class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need for recursion. This is simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

class A {
public:

    template<typename parser>
    void foohelper() {
        std::cout << "handled a " << typeid(parser).name() << std::endl;
        // do work here
    }

    template <typename... parsers>
    void foo() {
        using expand = int[];
        (void) expand { 0, (foohelper<parsers>(), 0)... };
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo<int, int, double, std::string>();
}
```

sample output:

```
handled a i
handled a i
handled a d
handled a NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
```

EDIT:

In response to the non-conforming microsoft compiler requirement, here's another version that does not rely on an unsized array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

class A {
public:

    template<typename parser>
    void foohelper() {
        std::cout << "handled a " << typeid(parser).name() << std::endl;
        // do work here
    }

    template <typename... parsers>
    void foo() {
        // c++ strictly does not allow 0-sized arrays.
        // so here we add a NOP just in case parsers is an empty type list
        using expand = int[1 + sizeof...(parsers)];
        (void) expand {
            (foohelper<void>(), 0),
            (foohelper<parsers>(), 0)...
        };
    }

};

// implement the NOP operation. Note specialisation is outside class definition.
template<> void
A::foohelper<void>() {}



int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo<int, int, double, std::string>();
    a.foo<>();
}
```

EDIT 2:

fuller example with prefix, postfix and inter-parser call-outs. Having written this much code, you'll probably start thinking, "Hey! I could implement a whole domain-specific language here!", and you'd be right.

However, much more complexity than this will probably earn you the eternal hatred of your colleagues, so I would avoid going down that route.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

class A {
public:

    template<typename parser>
    void foohelper() {
        std::cout << "handled a " << typeid(parser).name();
        // do work here
    }

    void prepare()
    {
        std::cout << "starting parsers: ";
    }

    void separator()
    {
        std::cout << ", ";
    }

    void nothing()
    {

    }

    void done() {
        std::cout << " done!" << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename... parsers>
    void foo() {
        // c++ strictly does not allow 0-sized arrays.
        // so here we add a NOP just in case parsers is an empty type list
        bool between = false;
        using expand = int[2 + sizeof...(parsers)];
        (void) expand {
            (prepare(), 0),
            ((between ? separator() : nothing()), between = true, foohelper<parsers>(), 0)...,
            (done(), 0)
        };
    }

};


int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo<int, int, double, std::string>();
    a.foo<>();
}
```

sample output:

```
starting parsers: handled a i, handled a i, handled a d, handled a NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE done!
starting parsers:  done!
```

Comment: Perfect! It even compiles with arm-none-eabi compiler.

Comment: I am getting an warning while compiling with VisualStudio 2013 (platform toolset v120), which causes crash when using with more complicated program than just a snippet. Warning:

"warning C4789: buffer '' of size 4 bytes will be overrun; 4 bytes will be written starting at offset 4"

There are as many warnings as template arguments with offset incrementing by 4 bytes.

Comment: sec, give me a moment to do a workaround for your compiler. Microsoft compilers are always a little delicate :)

Comment: @omicronns done. give that a try. I have tested it on clang with -Wpedantic.

Comment: Why do you need `foohelper<void>()`? Wasn't `0` good enough? As a side note, the original code works fine in VC++ 2015. Another side note: `foohelper<void>` defined like that will need to be `inline` to avoid the multiple definition problem the OP mentioned in the question.

Comment: In my convoluted thinking, supplying a NOP function is somehow clearer to a code reader since it's orthogonal in form the the rest of the template argument expansion.
It's also a nice demonstration that a code author could add a prefix function, suffix function (and indeed inter-parser 'separator' functions)

Comment: Ah, alright (I was just worried that there was something I was missing), but I think that's worth explaining in there, 'cause otherwise the comment in the code seems a bit confusing to me. And the thing about the `inline` still stands, I think.

Comment: updated the answer with 2nd edit to demonstrate the principle.